# Need to conditionally hide/exclude ChoiceFields in template OR set to disabled - many options; no success

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

maybe I'm going about this all wrong, but it's great to get a new set of eyes!

A very brief background; I'm asking people to rate the performance of a human heart in a video in 17 segments. They must rate all 17. However, they may have to do this at up to 4 different workloads (rest, low, high, recovery). It may be 1, it may be all 4. Rating can be 1 to 5. I've added the 6th option for reasons you can see later.

```
    segment_choices = (
    (1, "Normal"),
    (2, "Hypokinetic"),
    (3, "Akinetic"),
    (4, "Dyskinetic"),
    (5, "Aneursymal"),
    (6, "No image"),
)

segment_1_1 = models.IntegerField(choices=segment_choices,default=1)
segment_1_2 = models.IntegerField(choices=segment_choices,default=1)
segment_1_3 = models.IntegerField(choices=segment_choices,default=1)
segment_1_4 = models.IntegerField(choices=segment_choices,default=1)
segment_2_1 = models.IntegerField(choices=segment_choices,default=1)
...
segment_16_4 = models.IntegerField(choices=segment_choices,default=1)
segment_17_1 = models.IntegerField(choices=segment_choices,default=1)
segment_17_2 = models.IntegerField(choices=segment_choices,default=1)
segment_17_3 = models.IntegerField(choices=segment_choices,default=1)
segment_17_4 = models.IntegerField(choices=segment_choices,default=1)
```

The way I have this working at present is I don't draw the template tag for the IntegerField corresponding to a certain workload (e.g. rest) if the e.g. hr_rest value isn't set, like this:

```
{% if not echo.hr_rest = None %}<tr><td>Rest:</td><td>{{ ReportForm.segment_10_1 }}</td></tr>{% endif %}
```

This works nicely, but the problem is, of course, when I submit the form then if the form's fields aren't drawn then the values are missing and the form throws and error (I haven't set blank=True,null=True in the model because that seemed a dangerous way of going about this - I *DO* want to ensure that values aren't missed.

So I've got a few solutions

1. Draw the dropdown boxes when the questions are missing, but make them disabled. I don't actually mind even if they say 'normal' in them, as long as they are disabled, because the user will still be able to skip over them without being confused. I can then just 'ignore' these normal values at the data processing stage.
2. Draw the dropdown boxes but set the default value of the dropdown box when {% if not echo.hr_rest = None %} to 6 ("No image"); it probably doesn't need to be disabled then, as they'll see there's no image and move on. OR I could set the default to "No image" in Models.py and instead have it default to "Normal" when drawn for those that are drawn, doesn't really matter.
3. Draw the dropdown boxes as 'hidden' fields on certain conditions - this works very nicely of course because all the values will be sent to the view without the users noticing.

I have lots of solutions but none seem easy to implement and I'm not sure which is best.

What would you all advise?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `views.py` you can set the initial values of the fields and limit them like...

```
if <instance>.<whatever> is None:
    form.fields['<whatever>'].initial = 'No Image'
    form.fields['<whatever>'].choices = ((6, 'No Image'),)
```

Comment: That's great, thanks! Can I also set the disabled parameter in the view? I'll have a look!

Comment: Yes, `.disabled = True`

Comment: Also, since your only choice is `'No Image'`, I think you can do without the `.initial` setting. Give it a try.

Comment: Just be aware the disabled fields don't get submitted by HTML.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, how can I set multiple fields in one statement? Both `repform.fields['segment_17_2','segment_16_2'].choices` and `repform.fields['segment_17_2,segment_16_2'].choices` cause errors. Or is this not possible?

Comment: Try something like
`for f in repform.fields:
  if f.name.startswith('segment'):
    f.choices = ...`

I haven't tested this code, so you might need to make some adjustments.

Comment: Disregard the comment above. You obviously don't want to set all fields. Try this instead...
`for fieldName in ['segment_17_2', 'segment_16_2']:
    repform.fields[fieldName].choices = ...`

Comment: Actually I like your way better! I've tried doing this `for f in repform.fields:
      if (f.name.startswith('segment')) and (f.name.endswith('_2')):
       f.choices = ((6, 'No Image'),)` but sadly I get the error 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: Try f instead of f.name. As I said I haven't tested this part of the code :(

Comment: Got it, what we needed was `if (f.startswith('segment')) and (f.endswith('_2')):
       repform.fields[f].choices = ((6, 'No Image'),)`